# Can't get z-index working with absolute position of div elements

Tags: html, z-index

If you take a look at this website I am designing (http://babblers.in/main.html) there is a problem of z-index for div elements. Click on the stork & baby image at the bottom left. There is a close button in the expanded image which gets hidden under the sliding buttons.
The code for my main.css is:

```
    #SlidingButtons {display:block;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;left:320px;top:130px;width:840px;height:800px;z-index:4;}
    #Points {display:block;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;left:0px;top:170px;width:600px;height:730px;z-index:3;}
```

Sliding Buttons are the ones on the right
Points refers to the stork image and the selectable points on left

What do I do to get the expanded image above the sliding buttons?
Setting opacity for sliding buttons to .99 does not work.

Comment: It appears to be doing what you want it to be. What browser are you using?

Comment: IE11....whats wrong with it? Does it look okay to you?

Comment: I can only get it to work when I set slidingbuttons z-index to -1

Comment: but then slidingbuttons stops working

Comment: I'm using Chrome and it was working just fine. Now it isn't. Have you been making changes?

Comment: I have been making changes. You must have seen it when slidingbuttons z-index was set to -1....but that makes slidingbuttons stop working!

Comment: Ok, I've added a little detail as to why what you are doing isn't working for you.

Answer (score 2):

Z-index is notoriously tricky and picky, if you aren't 100% with it. Try this.

```
#Page {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 775px;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

EDIT: Scratch that, your entire web structure is the problem. Try not to use Z-Index, unless you need to.

Though here is a word of advice when using z-index. Z-index only applies in relation to sibling elements.

```
<div>

    <div class="one">

        <div class="four"></div>

    </div>

    <div class="two"></div>

    <div class="three"></div>

</div>
```

with the following CSS

```
.one{
z-index:1;
}

.two{
z-index:10;
}

.three{
z-index:100;
}

.four{
z-index:1000;
}
```

in this example div.four would appear lower than div.two, because div.four's parent has a z-index lower than div.two. As the z-index only applies in relation to sibling elements, even if an element has a higher z-index but it is in a sub element it won't have a higher screen z-index than its most top level parent element with a set z-index.

Comment: This is the most clear explanation how z-index works I found in more than a hour of searching.